# Function composition of pluck

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, currying

I'm learning functional programming in JS and I'm trying to write my own [`pluck`](https://ramdajs.com/docs/#pluck).

```
const curry = (f, arr = []) => (...args) =>
  (a => (a.length === f.length ? f(...a) : curry(f, a)))([
    ...arr,
    ...args,
  ]);
const map = curry((fn, arr) => arr.map(fn));
const pipe = (...fns) => x => fns.reduce((y, f) => f(y), x);
const prop = curry((key, obj) => obj[key]);

const pluck = pipe(prop, map);
```

But for some reason, `pluck` doesn't work. As far as I thought, this pluck would:

- Call `prop` with the key I invoke `pluck` with.
- So, `prop` with a curried `key` gets put as the function into `map`, which is returned from `pipe`.
- Then if I pass it an array, it should map over the array, applying `prop` with the key.

But,

```
pluck('foo')([{ foo: 'bar'}]);
[ƒ]
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The built-in `.map()` function passes 3 arguments to its callback: the array element value, the index, and the array itself.

Comment: You might want to use `a.length >= f.length`

Comment: @Bergi Why is that?

Comment: @J.Hesters See what `add = curry((a, b) => a+b)` returns for the calls `add(1)`, `add(1,2)`/`add(1)(2)` and `add(1,2,3)`/`add(1)(2,3)`. Given Pointy's explanation, this is exactly what happens to the curried (and partially applied) `prop` function when `map` calls it.

Comment: @Bergi, got it! Thank you for teaching it to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the built-in `.map()` function passes 3 arguments to the callback, your code is getting confused. It's easy to fix:

```
const map = curry((fn, arr) => arr.map(v => fn(v)));
```